# Space between svg and text

Tags: html, css, spacing

I have a `div` with `svg` and some text inside it. I need some space(say 2px) between `svg` and `text`. What are my options? 
Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttLv2n7g/)

Possible solutions:

1. Use requried number of `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`(aren't these old?)
2. select `svg` and give `padding-right` or `margin-right`

Any other ways to achieve this?

PS: I have encountered this many times and every time I use `&nbsp;` I feel guilty :(

Comment: What's wrong with `margin`? That's the accepted standard way to put space *between* elements. That said, the text should properly be in a textual element like a span or paragraph.

Comment: Ha ha , why afraid for padding and margin?

Comment: @Paulie_D Firstly, there is only one element(svg) and a text node. Also, I don't want to select the element just to give margin.

Comment: Yes...but text shouldn't really be in a textnode...even the W3C specifiy that one of the mistakes they made is not *requiring* that text be in a text element. But if you **won't/can't** select the SVG you have no other options since a text node cannot be selected.

Comment: @Krish I have these kind of elements all over the app. Performance wise, I think selecting `svg` everytime is bad.

Comment: Then you know the answer. Either restructure the HTML, use classes and specificity or use `&nbsp;`. Frankly the last option is worse than all other others.

Answer (score 1):

You don't like to use `margin-right` or `padding-right` for the element then you should go with required number of `&nbsp;` or `&#160;` , I hope that would be very bad practice to use lots of them for we need long spaces in any cases.